# Branding Managed Navigation / active node - Term store - How to set active node / page / site in the html code

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, css, html, managed-navigation

Is there a good way of marking the active node in the managed navigation?

ex: if you browse in the menu to a node on level 3, how can you mark that spesific node as "active"

```
Root node
 - subsite1 
 - subsite2
 - subsite3
    - subsubsite1
    - subsubsite2 (marked as active if you are on page)
 - subsite4
 - subsite5
 .............
```